# How to loop an animated mask?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I'm trying to make a **loop from an animated mask**, but each time I introduce my loop expression: `loopOut (type="cycle", numKeyframes = 0)`, After Effects is telling me that:

> "Expression is deactivated, because of line 1 and that the layer doesn't allow loop"

I have tried to use the **pre-expressions** from the application, but it still doesn't work:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong or what else can I do to loop the mask?

Answer (score 5):

This expression is **not supported for Mask Path Property**, because it's a *User Defined Property*, see the note of the error message.

#### Workaround

[image]

*Mask Path animation once*

1. **Precompose your layer** an with the animated mask (one time) by *Selecting the Layer > Right Click > Precompose* (and move all attributes in the new composition)
2. **Enable Time Remapping** on your new created composition *(Right Click on the composition > Time > Time Remapping)*, this extends the length of the layer to infinity
3. Add `loopOut(type="cycle")` expression to the **Time Remapping Property** by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking the stop watch left beside the properties name

[image]

*Time Remapping enabled on the new composition and expresssion applied*

#### Example

[image]

*Example using 3 keyframes (third is same as first) and using `loopOut()` only*

Answer (score 4):

Another option if you don't want to create a pre-comp:

Make your mask and set the keyframes and apply this expression to the mask path property:

```
valueAtTime(time % key(numKeys).time)
```

This is basically an implementation of the loopOut function, but it works for all properties, including custom ones like mask shapes.

[image]

**How it works**: `valueAtTime` returns the value of the property at a given time, so to loop the property we need a value that goes from 0 and rises until the playhead gets to the last keyframe and then the value loops back to 0.

The expression `key(numKeys).time` returns the time of the last key (e.g. if there are 3 keys it will be `key(3).time`). The `%` operator is the modulus operator, which gives you the remainder when you divide the first term by the second. So if you find the remainder when dividing the current time (`time`) by the time of the last keyframe it will return a value that starts at 0 and rises in synch with `time` until the playhead reaches the last keyframe at which point the current time will divide exactly into the time of the last keyframe, so the remainder will go back to 0 then start rising in synch with the playhead, rinse, repeat.

A useful feature of this expression is that you can speed it up and down by multiplying `time` by another factor, e.g. `time * 2 % key(numKeys).time` would play back the animation in double speed.

Comment: Nice one, thanks Stib! That's a very nice, elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (numKeys >1 && time > key(numKeys).time){
  t1 = key(1).time;
  t2 = key(numKeys).time;
  span = t2 - t1;
  delta = time - t2;
  t = delta%span;
  valueAtTime(t1 + t)
}else
  value
```

courtesy of the Master Expressionist Dan Ebberts in this thread:

https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/227/20661#22869